# Powershell get user profile information

Tags: powershell

I have script who get all users.
How can I get information in profile? 
- about
- description
- assignement

Comment: Please share your current script code and also try to clarify your question to avoid it being closed as "Unsure what you're asking"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you want to access profile of single user following is the script**

```
$mySiteUrl = "http://mysite"
$adAccount = "DOMAIN\chill"
$upAttribute = "WebSite"
$upAttributeValue = “http://get-spscripts.com”

#Get site objects and connect to User Profile Manager service
$site = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

#Check to see if user profile exists
if ($profileManager.UserExists($adAccount))
{
    #Get user profile and change the value
    $up = $profileManager.GetUserProfile($adAccount)
    $up[$upAttribute].Value = $upAttributeValue
    $up.Commit()
}
else
{
    write-host "Profile for user"$adAccount "cannot be found"
}

#Dispose of site object
$site.Dispose()
```

**If you want to access all user profile properties**

```
#Get Site for Service context
$Site = Get-SPSite -Limit 1

$ServiceContext = Get-SPServiceContext($Site)

$ProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)

$Profiles = $ProfileManager.GetEnumerator()    #Load all profiles into array
```

Comment: Thanks! And if anyone will get `New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging` then setting correct permissions will help: https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/when-setting-the-mysitehosturl-i-get-a-userprofileapplicationnotavailableexception/